# User from the first website is logged to another website issue

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, session-cookies, session-state

I created two websites in `ASP .NET MVC4`. Both are having **different** names.

I registered  a new "**userA**" for the **website #1** and signed in.

When I start the **website #2** I see that the "**userA**" is already logged in.

How is it possible?

What do I have to do so **website #2** is not going to work like that?

What exactly I have to change to get rid of that? web.config, cookies or what and how?

Thanks!

Comment: Both running as localhost?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Yes. But they have different ports.

Comment: Yes, but same domain...

Comment: @MikeSmithDev I am starting locally 2 Visual Studio projects

Comment: How are you creating the cookie? are you using `membership`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the name of the Forms Authentication Ticket, by default it is set to .ASPXAUTH which can cause issues if you're running multiple apps locally.  This caught me up a few weeks back.

```
<forms 
   name=".myappauth" 
   loginUrl="~/Account/Login" 
   protection="All"
   timeout="30">
   <credentials>...</credentials>
</forms>
```

MSDN Documentation
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Can you explain this name=".myappauth"  pls? I am working locally and have started 2 visual studio.

Comment: That will be the name for your Forms Authentication cookie, you can name it whatever you want. The reason you're having an issue is because you're running two websites locally on your machine that are both set by default to use a cookie named ASPXAUTH so logging into one website creates a valid cookie for the other website because it using the same name.  Set it to something unique.